# How to solve equation with ceil function

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For a problem I came out with following equation:
$$\left\lceil\frac{x_1}{k}\right\rceil + \left\lceil\frac{x_2}{k}\right\rceil + \left\lceil\frac{x_3}{k}\right\rceil + \cdots + \left\lceil\frac{x_n}{k}\right\rceil = v,$$

Here, $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ and $v$ are known. I need to find out the minimum value of $\boldsymbol{k}$ for which the above equation holds.

I tried using ceiling properties but not able to come up with any solution.

Comment: I'm not aure, but I think it depends on what the value of known constants are? It would be helpful if you gave us those values

Comment: The values of constants are not fixed. I need to solve this equation for different set of (X, V) values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming everything is positive here.  For starters, you need $V$ to be less than or equal to the sum of the $X$s and greater than or equal to $n$.  Now you can just do bisection with $k$ ranging from $1$ to the maximum of the $Xn$

Better, you can start by ignoring the ceiling functions, and get $k=\frac {\sum x_i}v$ as a lower bound.  Each ceiling adds $1$ at the most, so $k'=\frac {\sum x_i}{v-n}$ is an upper bound.

Comment: This requires doing binary search for k between 1 and max(X). As, X can have a huge value and binary search might take time. Is there any faster method for this?

Comment: @BarryCipra:  yes, I am.  I'll add that.

Comment: This might be possible that v = n then how should we decide the upper bound?

Comment: If $v=n$ you just want all the fractions less than $1$ so any $k$ greater than all the $x_i$ will work.